# how to add new data in next line in mysql with existing ctp file?

Tags: php

Controller

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $a = $_POST['category'];
    $b = $_POST['subcategory'];
    $c = $_POST['category1'];
    $d = $_POST['subcategory1'];
    // i have checked whether values are comming to controller r not

    echo $a;

    echo $b;

    echo $c;

    echo $d;
    //They are comming 

    // I have category and subcategory columns in my databse

    // I want to store $a and $b in one row ,$c and $d values in the next row of my database . 

    // I have written like this


    $this->Bill->create();
    if ($this->Bill->save($this->request->data)) {
        $this->Bill->saveField('category',$a);
        $this->Bill->saveField('subcategory',$b);
        $this->Bill->saveField('category',$c);
        $this->Bill->saveField('subcategory',$d);
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The Bill has been saved'));
            return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'Bills','action' => 'view'));
    }
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The bill could not be saved'));*/
}
// but $c and $d  values are only storing  in row.
```

How to store $a and $b in one row ,$c and $d values in the next row of my database ?

please help me ...!

Comment: I guess you shoud, call ` $this->Bill->create()` twice, it woud be helpfull if you share which framework do you use

Comment: can you add db structure of Bill table.

Comment: Post data is all messed up, it should an array of key value pair. that is the main problem. is data is coming from an html from? can you post your form? it will help fix the issue.

Comment: i am using cake php frame work

Comment: The data is comming from html form

Answer (score 0):

May be you must create an object to each of them.

```
        $bill_1=new Bill;
        $bill_2=new Bill;
        $this->Bill->create();
        $bill_1->saveField('category',$a);
        $bill_1->saveField('subcategory',$b);
        $bill_2->saveField('category',$c);
        $bill_2->saveField('subcategory',$d);
        if($bill_1->save() && $bill_2->save()){
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The Bill has been saved'));
            return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'Bills','action' => 'view'));
        }

        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The bill could not be saved'));*/
```

I don't know how your method save the data. I just want to say that you must create an object to create a row. CMIIW.

Comment: your welcome. if you get another way, keep sharing...:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to build an array of key value pair then save it in your database table

```
$data = array (
    array(
        'a' => $_POST['category'],
        'b' => $_POST['subcategory']

    ),
    array(
        'a' => $_POST['category'],
        'b' => $_POST['subcategory'],
    ),
);
```

Then pass the array to insert query. The root of the problem is how your data is coming out from the $_POST. It should have been formatted and sent as an array of key value pairs. 
Hope this help.